# Having trouble with passing user defined parameters inside my object

Tags: java

I'm being asked to pass more arguments to match my constructor but I have no idea what to pass into them.

I have multiple instance variables but only a few of them will be defined by the user (the vertices) and the others are going to defined with their respective methods. If I take everything except my vertices outside of my constructor to solve the error I am left with my final output being left as 0 for most of my reports.

Is my constructor the problem or the parameters in my object at fault?

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Triangle {

    //instance variables
    private double VertAx, VertAy, VertBx, VertBy, VertCx, VertCy;
    private double lengthAB, lengthBC, lengthCA;
    private double Perimeter, Area;
    private double H = Perimeter/2;



    //Triangle Constructor 
    public Triangle(double userVertAx, double userVertAy, double userVertBx, double userVertBy, double userVertCx, double userVertCy, double userlengthAB, double userlengthBC, double userlengthCA, double userPerimeter, double userArea, double userH) {


        userVertAx = this.VertAx;
        userVertAy = this.VertAy;
        userVertBx = this.VertBx;
        userVertBy = this.VertBy;
        userVertCx = this.VertCx;
        userVertCy = this.VertCy;


        userlengthAB = this.lengthAB;
        userlengthBC = this.lengthBC;
        userlengthCA = this.lengthCA;

        userPerimeter = this.Perimeter;
        userArea = this.Area;
        userH = this.H;



    }





    public double lengthAB(double userVertAx, double userVertAy, double userVertBx, double userVertBy) {
        return lengthAB = Math.sqrt( (Math.pow((userVertBx - userVertAx), 2)) + (Math.pow((userVertBy - userVertAy), 2)));


    }

    public double lengthBC(double userVertBx, double userVertBy, double userVertCx, double userVertCy) {
        return lengthBC = Math.sqrt( (Math.pow((userVertCx - userVertBx), 2)) + (Math.pow((userVertCy - userVertBy), 2)));


    }

    public double lengthCA(double userVertCx, double userVertCy, double userVertAx, double userVertAy) {
        return lengthCA = Math.sqrt( (Math.pow((userVertAx - userVertCx), 2)) + (Math.pow((userVertAy - userVertCy), 2)));

    }


    public void setPerimeter(double userlengthAB, double userlengthBC, double userlengthCA) {
        Perimeter = userlengthAB + userlengthBC + userlengthCA;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return Perimeter;
    }



    public void setArea(double userlengthAB, double userlengthBC, double userlengthCA, double userH) {



        Area = Math.sqrt(userH*(userH-userlengthAB)*(userH-userlengthBC)*(userH-userlengthCA)); 
    }

    public double getArea() {
        double Area = getArea();
        return Area;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Vertices: A(%f, %f) B(%f, %f) C(%f, %f)\nSide Lengths: AB=%f BC=%f CA=%f\nPerimeter: %f\nArea: %f", VertAx, VertAy, VertBx, VertBy, VertCx, VertCy, lengthAB, lengthBC, lengthCA, Perimeter, Area);
    }

    }

public class TriangleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner Vertices = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Triangle Test enter each coordinate of your three vertices SEPERATELY");


        System.out.println("Enter Vertex A X");
        Double VAX = Vertices.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Vertex A Y");
        Double VAY = Vertices.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Vertex B X");
        Double VBX = Vertices.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Vertex B Y");
        Double VBY = Vertices.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Vertex C X");
        Double VCX = Vertices.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Vertex C Y");
        Double VCY = Vertices.nextDouble();




        //ERROR  
        Triangle UserTriangle = new Triangle(VAX, VAY, VBX, VBY, VCX, VCY);
        //ERROR ^
        UserTriangle.lengthAB(VAX, VAY, VBX, VBY);

        UserTriangle.lengthBC(VBX, VBY, VCX, VCY);

        UserTriangle.lengthCA(VCX, VCY, VAX, VAY);

        UserTriangle.getPerimeter();
        UserTriangle.getArea();


        System.out.println(UserTriangle.toString());


    }
}
```

I am expecting some way to pass the right parameters into my `UserTriangle` but I am confused as to how. Thank you for any help anyone can provide. My understanding with classes and objects were good with implementing user input but this one seems so tricky to me considering some of the variables are defined in methods and some are defined by the user.

Comment: Your constructor certainly has a problem: please rethink what `userVertAx = this.VertAx` actually means. It doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions. Class names `PascalCase`, variable names and methods `camelCase`, constants (`static final`) `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Constructor called with a mismatched number of arguments

You defined your constructor as accepting *12 arguments*, but then you called it with only *6 arguments*. This is the error you're referring to. To solve this you have 3 options

- Provide all the 12 arguments the constructor needs
- Define your constructor as receiving 6 arguments
- Refactor **(see below for instructions)**, which is the way to go in my opinion

## Reverse the initialization statements in your constructor

To initialize your attributes write `this.VertAx = userVertAx` instead of `userVertAx = this.VertAx;` (reverse the statement basically)

This goes for all the other attributes too (userlengthAB, userPerimeter, etc...)

## Note

It's better to use the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) so you can make the difference say between *attributes* and *classes*. Attributes and variables should start with a *lowercase* and classes with an *uppercase*.

## Edit: Refactoring suggestion

An even better writing is to use **less arguments in your constructor**. Having too many arguments is considered a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and will make your code less readable/maintainable, etc...

To handle that you can encapsulate some concepts in classes. For example you can have

```
public class Vertex {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    public Vertex(double x, double y) { 
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

public class TriangleVertices {
    private vertexA;
    private vertexB;
    private vertexC;
    public TriangleVertices (Vertex a, Vertex b, Vertex c) {
        vertexA = a;
        vertexB = b;
        vertexC = c;
    }
}

public class Triangle {
    private TriangleVertices vertices;
    // other attributes

    // You have now 5 arguments less!
    public Triangle(TriangleVertices vertices, // other attributes) {
        this.vertices = vertices;
        // Initialize other attributes
    }
}
```

Comment: I see we haven't talked about refactoring yet but I can see the strengths in introducing this suggestion in many of my codes. We were told to only have 2 classes called Triangle and TriangleTest I can definitely try to see if my instructor would be okay of trying this out. As for the other two solutions you mentioned It seems to me they would be "bandaids" in this situation because if tried to provide all 12 arguments I am left with an error that shows that they have not been initialized? If I define my constructor with only 6 then my final output is reported with all zeroes except the length.

Answer (score 0):

Here "this" is a keyword which points the constructor to the variables that are declared in the created class (in your case created class is Triangle). we use "this" keyword when 
the variable of parameter has the same name as the variable declared in the created class.For example;

```
class A {
int NewVar;
A (double NewVar){
this.NewVar = NewVar;  //here this.NewVar is pointing to NewVar of type int
}
}
```

Change this in your code. This might solve your problem.

```
public Triangle(double userVertAx, double userVertAy, double userVertBx, double userVertBy, double userVertCx, double userVertCy, double userlengthAB, double userlengthBC, double userlengthCA, double userPerimeter, double userArea, double userH) {


     this.VertAx = userVertAx;
     this.VertAy = userVertAy;
     this.VertBx = userVertBx;
     this.VertBy = userVertBy;
     this.VertCx = userVertCx;
     this.VertCy = userVertCy;


    this.lengthAB = userlengthAB;
    this.lengthBC = userlengthBC;
    this.lengthCA = userlengthCA ;

    this.Perimeter = userPerimeter ;
    this.Area = userArea;
    this.H = userH ;



}
```